# How to decide if java.util.Timer is running

Tags: java, android, timer

I write my own `Timer` class, which fires a single execution of `TimerTask`. In my **singleton Timer**, there is `private boolean isRunning`. If `isRunning==true`, other threads won't fire the Timer.

```
public class DBconnectDelayTimer extends Timer {
    /**
     *  Indicates if the Timer is running
     */
    private boolean isRunning;
    public DBconnectDelayTimer() {
        super();
        isRunning = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
        isRunning = true;
        super.schedule(task, delay);
    }
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
}
```

My question is, in which method should I set `isRunning` back to `false`?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One naive solution is to wrap the task argument in another task that resets `isRunning` upon completion:

```
@Override
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) {
    isRunning = true;
    super.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Note that this only works if no more than one task is scheduled at a time, which is difficult to enforce without proper synchronization. It also breaks `Timer`'s promise to throw an `IllegalStateException` if a single task is scheduled twice.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your "Note that".